# Cables on LED mirror

Tags: power, led, batteries, mirror

I have bought an LED mirror that is powered by a battery.
Unfortunately, it didn't work after charging the battery and I tried to see if the cables were joined correctly.

I was too dumb to take a picture before removing the "cable holders" and since I have no knowledge of anything electrical, I have no idea which cable to join.

I made a picture of the cables... can you please tell me which ones I have to join for it to work?

[image]

Thanks in advance

## Edit:

[image]

## Battery:

1x Red
1x Black

## LED

1x Blue
1x Brown to On/Off Switch

## Charger

1x Brown
1x Blue

## On/Off Switch

1x Brown to LED
1x Brown

Comment: Try snipping the small white strip and spread the wires a bit so we can se what goes where. It will make it easier to provide a good guess.

Comment: @JakobHalskov Unfortunately I cant cut the white strip because of warranty reasons but I've added a better photo and a description, does that help?

Comment: You have enough contacts there to "beep" it with multimeter

Comment: It looks like you have a lithium ion battery with red and black leads, and those leads are touching, or almost touching. That is extremely dangerous.

Comment: Check battery voltage Red + Blk - and then connect +ve to brown(2) and - to blue(2). I agree it looks like battery is shorted in  2nd photo

Comment: While rewiring and testing the assembly initially disconnect the two halves of the white connector coming from the battery.  Only after you think you have the correct connections reconnect the two sides of the battery connector, if the system doesn't light up then immediately disconnect the battery connector.  This should reduce the chance of burning up something with the battery incorrectly connnected.

Answer (score 0):

BROWN and RED are PROBABLY +ve in each case:

Use Ohmmeter with 9V battery.
Set to low Ohms range.
Place probes across LED leads
Brown LED lead is PROBABLY +ve but may not be.
Blue  LED lead is PROBABLY -ve but may not be.
In one of two orientations LED should glow very very very dimly.
For that connection - determine polarity of meter leads (red MAY NOT be positive in this mode)

If no light either way.
Obtain 1000 Ohm resistor.

Connect battery black to LED blue
VIA 1000 OHM RESISTOR connect Battery brown to LED brown.
Does LED light very dimly?
If not, reverse battery connections and still using series 1000 ohm resistor try again.
If LED lights this way all is well.

If LED lights neither way, find someone local to help - but one or other way should work.

IF LED never worked it may be dead,

MOST LIKELY:

Battery red brown via switch to LED brown.
Battery black to LED brown.